# Functions return leaf of tree

Tags: java, arrays, tree

I have tree structure:

```
public class Tree{
  int topSize = 10 ;
  Tree[] children2 = new Tree[topSize];
  Tree parent;
  String data;
  int i = 0;
   public void addChild(Tree child) {
      child.setParent(this);
      this.children2[i++] = child;
   }
}
```

I use it in my program, and I have for example:

```
example 1:                           example 2:
          F                             H
         /                             / \
        E                             I   J
       /                             /
      D                             T
     /
    C
```

I want function that give me a leaf as result:
example 1: function should return an array with : C(tree node)
example 2: function return me result in array[0] = T(tree node which have in data T), array[1] = J(tree node).

I need for flattening the tress in example 1 and example 2 to :

```
example 1         example 2
solution          solution
    F                 H
 /  |  \            / | \
E   D  C           I  J  T
```

I have the following function that accepts a leaf as argument:

```
public static Tree find(Tree edge){
    if(edge != edge.parent){
        edge.parent = find(edge.parent);
        edge.parent.addChild(edge);
    }
    return edge.parent;
}
```

So in for example 1 I use: find(C)
For example 2 I think that I should use: find(T) and then find(edge J). 
 In main i give array that contains:

```
treeArray[0]
data="d",                          children[] -    children[3]->data="c",children[0]->data="a", children[0]=null                                                                                                   
                                    /     \       
children[0]->data="b",children[0]=null    children[1]->data="b",children[0]=null
```

I have the same children but then I delete it so I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are after a method like the following :

```
  public static void findLeaves(Tree root, List<Tree> leaves){

        //iterate over children 
        for(Tree child : root.children2) { //better use getter 

            //if child has no children it is a leaf. Add it to list 
            if(! hasChildren(child))  leaves.add(child);
            //if child has children, check them 
            else  findLeaves(child, leaves);
        }

        return ;
  } 

  static boolean hasChildren(Tree child) {

      for(int i=0; i < child.children2.length; i++) {

          if(child.children2[i] != null) return true;
      }
      return false;
  }
```

The method should  add all leaves (nodes with no children) to `List<Tree> leaves` (which you can convert to an array if you need to).

Use it by :

```
List<Tree> leaves = new ArrayList<>();//a list to hold leaves after method runs
findLeaves(root, leaves);
```

Please note:
1. I couldn't run and check the method. Please check carefully.
2. The method is not null safe. Both `root` and `leaves` should not be null

Comment: I add to my post how look like my array for example. Your function give me error: NullPointerException in if(child.children2.length == 0)  leaves.add(root);, i debug it and that not work since i have always array with size = 10, 10 is for example i give this value in my main later but i must use array in my structure, so alway children2 have length = 10, and when root have not children, then root have array children2[10] with null in chldren2[0],children[1]... Do you know how change your function ?

Comment: I changed  if(child.children2[0] == null)  leaves.add(root); and now i have not get error but in leaves there are only parent of root, not leaf

Comment: Yes it isn't minimal sorry, but happily I worked it out. This function : `    <pre><code>public static void findLeaves(Tree root, List<Tree> leaves){
     int k =0;
     if(root.i == 0)leaves.add(root);
     while(k < root.i){//iterate over children
      Tree child2 = root.children2[k];
      if(! hasChildren(child2))  leaves.add(child2);
      //if child has children, check them
      else  findLeaves(child2, leaves);
      k++;
     }
        return ;
  }<pre><code>and it works, thank you for your help.

Comment: I am not sure what `root.i` is and how can it  `==0` ?

Comment: Awesome, great solution.  I used this as a model for getting the bottom level elements in multi-layered shadow doms on a web page.